# Ribbon control double click functionality

Tags: wpf, ribbon, double-click, ribbon-control

As we are aware double clicking the tabs on ribbon control opens the menu & keeps it fixed until the user double clicks again on either of the tabs. This basically resizes the row beneath the ribbon. **Is there a way by which I can control this resize behavior?** I want it to resize it from the upper portion of the row but keep the bottom portion of the row fixed. The purpose of doing this is a user control is placed in the row beneath the ribbon which has a tool bar at the bottom. As a consequence of double clicking the **tool bar goes beneath the third row & gets hidden** & is visible only when user double clicks on the ribbon again. So if I can control the resize behavior to keep the row fixed from the bottom I would be able to view the toolbar even when user double clicks the ribbon. Is there a way I can achieve this?
Any help/suggestion would be appreciated.

Edit: Adding a sample XAML for clearer understanding.

```
<RibbonWindow>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height=30/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Ribbon Grid.Row=0/>
        <UserControlWithEmbeddedToolbarHere Grid.Row=1/>
        <!--The toolbar is embedded within the user control &
            placed at the bottom of the user control-->
        <StatusBarHere Grid.Row=2/>
    </Grid>
</RibbonWindow>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your window should contain a MinHeight in the RowDefinitions, which is the height of the toolbar:

```
<Window>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
           <RowDefinition Height="*" MinHeight="40"/>
           <RowDefinition Height="30"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Ribbon Grid.Row="0">
        </Ribbon>
        <UserControlHere Grid.Row="1">
        </UserControlHere>
        <StatusBar Grid.Row="2">
        </StatusBar>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Your UserControl with toolbar:

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
           <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid>
           Everything else
        </Grid>
        <ToolbarHere Grid.Row="1">
        </ToolbarHere>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

In your user control, by specifying a height for your toolbar, you 'ensure' that it'll be given a space in your grid. Height="*" is 'everything else' after "Auto" (which is the space your toolbar needs) has been allocated.

Your window is creating space for the ribbon first, then the statusbar, THEN your usercontrol (because of Height="*"). If your rendered ribbon is (let's just say...) 40 and your status bar is 30 as you mentioned and your window height is 80, your usercontrol will only be of height 10 (80-40-30), thus you might not see your toolbar in your usercontrol.

Consider adding a scrollviewer wrapping your usercontrol, or setting a minimum height to your window.

Comment: I tried this earlier, doesn't work. 
**The toolbar isnt a separate control it is within the user control itself.** The issue I'm facing is since the toolbar is placed in the lower half of the user control it collapses or hides behind the status bar (grid displaying certain details having labels) when a user double clicks the ribbon bar. I have added a sample XAML for your convienience above.

Comment: Thanks for replying. It still doesn't work.
Reason: Even after I set the minimum height for the user control, the space available for the user control after ribbon has expanded is easily more than the min height. And the embedded toolbar (toolbar is in the bottom of the user control) still collapses.
Can you please explain what you mean by adding a scroll viewer wrapping the user control? Do you mean when the window reduces in size, a scroller appears & I can scroll down to see the toolbar?

Comment: From "And the embedded toolbar (toolbar is in the bottom of the user control) still collapses", it seems to me that you did not define your toolbar according to my snippet above. You have to define your toolbar in the user control to use Height="Auto" and **everything else to be Height="*"** so that it will always show your toolbar, **then** you add this usercontrol to your window, which has MinHeight defined.

Comment: My user control has been defined exactly like your code snippet. But still it doesn't seem to work.